# Why do i have ''str' object has no attribute 'copy'' error?

Tags: python, data-cleaning, attributeerror

i'm currently trying to automatize data cleaning and i found a repository on GitHub that i'm currently trying to run on my device, but i have an error at running, here's the code:

```
from AutoClean.autoclean import AutoClean
import pandas as pd
resultat = 'result(11).xlsx'
pipeline = AutoClean(resultat)
for pipeline in self.pipeline:
    pipeline.output
```

The error i'm getting is:

```
File "C:\Users\radia\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\AutoClean\autoclean.py", line 64, in __init__        
    output_data = input_data.copy()
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'copy'
```

Thanks for reading me,

Answer (score 3):

According to the autoclean documentation, you need to pass in a `pandas.DataFrame` into the constructor, not a string as you have done.

try

```py
from AutoClean.autoclean import AutoClean
import pandas as pd
resultat = pd.read_excel('result(11).xlsx')
pipeline = AutoClean(resultat)
for pipeline in self.pipeline:
    pipeline.output
```

You will probably need to pass some params to `read_excel()` to get it to load the right excel tab, etc...

Answer (score 2):

From the Readme for [Autoclean](https://github.com/elisemercury/AutoClean)

> AutoClean takes a Pandas dataframe as input

You are passing a string, not a dataframe.